# Delete duplicate rows with older/newer date

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I'd like to delete rows with duplicated IDs but only the one with the later date.

Example:
Highlighted rows are duplicated and the Red rows are the rows I'd like to delete.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `where` clause in the `delete`:

```
delete from t
    where t.datetime > (select min(t2.datetime)
                        from t t2
                        where t2.id = t.id
                       );
```

If you don't actually want to delete the rows, but just run a query and not see the red ones:

```
select id, min(datetime)
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill depending on how big your table is, but you could create a duplicate table (different name) make the id primary key.. the do INSERT IGNORE INTO new table name SELECT * FROM old table ORDER BY ID...then rename the tables make the duplicate table your real table AFTER renaming your real table to something else